# mongodb: same field value, but cannot find the specific document using find() function

Tags: mongodb, find

Put my question more clear: I am using mongodb, each document in the collection looks like:

```
{
  u'cell_latlng': {
    u'type': u'Polygon',
    u'coordinates': [
      [
        [
          ...
        ],
        [
          ...
        ],
        [
          ...
        ],
        [
          ...
        ]
      ]
    ]
  },
  u'self': {
    u'Bus Line': 1,
    u'Meeting Room': 1,
    u'Neighborhood': 1,
    u'Home (private)': 1,
    u'Food': 1,
    u'High School': 2,
    u'Elementary School': 1,
    u'Beach': 1,
    u'Other Repair Shop': 1
  },
  u'_id': ObjectId('5545bed4e139c7dcde660f5a'),
  u'point_latlng': {
    u'type': u'Point',
    u'coordinates': [
      ...
    ]
  },
  u'area': 100
}
```

Now I need to find a specific doc in the collection (the collection is called citymap). I know the value of the field 'self' and the value is called feature[0], so I just use:

```
results = citymap.find({'self':feature[0]})
```

However,

```
results.count() == 0
```

I check the feature[0] again and I am sure it is:

```
feature[0] = {u'Bus Line': 1, u'Meeting Room': 1, u'Neighborhood': 1, u'Home (private)': 1, u'Food': 1, u'High School': 2, u'Elementary School': 1, u'Beach': 1, u'Other Repair Shop': 1}
```

which is exactly the same as that in the doc, so why cannot I find this doc using this sentence?

Great thanks to any help

Comment: why you not create your `feature` value like this`self.u'Bus Line': 1, self.u'Meeting Room': 1,....`

Comment: ah, because this is also used for other things, and we need to keep this format, so any good idea fix this problem?

Comment: So this case you should iterate over `feature` object and append every key with `self.` and then form new object and check with that new objects.

Answer (score 0):

Let's check this script. Suppose your `feature` object like this

`var feature = {u'Bus Line': 1, u'Meeting Room': 1, u'Neighborhood': 1, u'Home (private)': 1, u'Food': 1, u'High School': 2, u'Elementary School': 1, u'Beach': 1, u'Other Repair Shop': 1}`

Iterate over `feature` object and append every keys as `self` and push them into new object. Check below function:

```
var appendSelf = {};

function appendData(data) {
  for (var k in data) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
      appendSelf["self.".concat(k)] = data[k]; //append self to every keys and set it's respective values
    }
  }
}
```

Now call this function as `appendData(feature)` on console if you type `appendSelf` then it shows object with appending `self` like this

```
> appendSelf 
{
  "self.u'Bus Line": 1,
  "self.u'Meeting Room": 1,
  "self.u'Neighborhood": 1,
  "self.u'Home (private)": 1,
  "self.u'Food": 1,
  "self.u'High School": 4,
  "self.u'Elementary School": 1,
  "self.u'Beach": 1,
  "self.u'Other Repair Shop": 1
}
```

So use this `appendSelf` in find criteria as `citymap.find(appendSelf[0]).pretty()` it show expected result.